# Opening port in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, port, firewall

I'm trying to run a dedicated game server on a VM.
I did it on a pc at home by opening the port in the firewall and the router.
but when I try it on the VM it is being blocked by "DefaultRule_DenyAllInBound", even though I created a rule with higher Priority to allow it.
am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

turns out the source port need to be *

Comment: I had made the same mistake, the source could be from any port but the destination port is for which we are applying the actual rule

Answer (score 0):

I know your issue was inbound connectivity testing and you have a public IP associated to your NIC. I figured it was good info to share anyhow.

If you do not have a Public IP associated with your NIC you might get denied. I for example was trying to connect out via SMBv3 to a an Azure Storage account via Azure default internet access (no Public IP associated to my NIC) and got the same message. I added a Public IP to my NIC and then go out without issue.

Comment: Since your reply doesn't address the question I think it will be better if you just write a small comment and delete this answer.